# C++ Linked List deleting the wrong item

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to review data structures and implement a basic linked list. When I run this code, I get the following output:

> 3  4  6
>
> 1 was found and deleted  4 was found and deleted
>
> 3

4 should be deleted, but obviously 1 should not, and I'm wondering where the error in my code/logic is.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class List {

private:

    struct node {
        int data;
        node * next;
    };

    node * head;
    node * curr;
    node * temp;

public:

    List();

    void addNode(int newData);
    void deleteNode(int delData);
    void printList();

};

int main() {


    List test;

    test.addNode(3);
    test.addNode(4);
    test.addNode(6);

    test.printList();

    cout << endl << endl;

    test.deleteNode(1);
    test.deleteNode(4);

    cout << endl << endl;

    test.printList();



}

List::List(){

    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

void List::addNode(int newData){

    node * n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = newData;

    if (head != NULL) { // List is intact

        curr = head; // if List is not empty, make curr equal to the head, and start at the beginning of the list.

        while(curr->next != NULL) { // Get to last item on the list
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n; // Use the last item, and point to the new node.
    }

    else { // empty list
        head = n; // new node is the head of the list.
    }
}

void List::deleteNode(int delData){

    node * n = new node;

    temp = head;
    curr = head;

    if (head != NULL) {
        while (curr->next != NULL && curr->data != delData) {
            temp = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        if (curr == NULL) {
            cout << delData << " was not found in the list\n";
            delete n;
        }
        else {
            n = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            temp->next = curr;
            delete n;

            cout << delData << " was found and deleted\n";
        }
    }
}

void List::printList(){

    curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `List::deleteNode` leaks `node * n` if `head == nullptr`. Consider using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw owning pointers to avoid these kinds of errors.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Learning [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) will help immensely in finding out what happens.

Comment: Why are you creating a new node in `deleteNode`? It's deleting things, not creating anything.

Comment: In `deleteNode`, Your while condition is `curr->next != NULL` but then you check for `cur == NULL` after termination. Seems like that condition will never be fulfilled, so else is entered even if the current data does not match.

Comment: Addendum: It is not used to distinguish between the two conditions inside `while`. The condition would need to be `curr->next != NULL` if you truly wanted to check which one failed. Check every assignment of `curr` and you will see that `NULL` can never be assigned to it (only in the else-clause)

Comment: Draw a list with boxes and arrows on paper and figure out what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, it seems like I just needed to change if (curr == NULL) to if (curr->next == NULL). Since I was reaching the last item on the list, when I checked my conditional, it was not null, and ended up deleting the last item.

Answer (score 2):

The following line allocates a new node.

```
node * n = new node;
```

As already pointed out in the comments, it is not clear why the `deleteNode()` is doing that. The subsequent lines of `delete n` is actually deleting this new node, not one of the nodes in the list.

I would try writing `deleteNode()` something like this:

```
void List::deleteNode(int delData) {
  // Empty list
  if (!head) return;

  // The first node is to be deleted
  if (head->data == delData) {
    node * old_head = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete old_head;
    return;
  }

  // A non-first node is to be deleted
  for (node * cur = head; cur; cur = cur->next) {
    if (cur->next && cur->next->data == delData) {
      node * del_node = cur->next;
      cur->next = cur->next->next;
      delete del_node;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem in your code was that the condition :

```
curr-> next !=NULL  had to be replaced by curr!= NULL
```

since the code stops one step before it requires to stop.

Here is your working code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class List {

private:

    struct node {
        int data;
        node * next;
    };

    node * head;
    node * curr;
    node * temp;

public:

    List();

    void addNode(int newData);
    void deleteNode(int delData);
    void printList();

};

int main() {


    List test;

    test.addNode(3);
    test.addNode(4);
    test.addNode(6);

    test.printList();

    cout << endl << endl;

    test.deleteNode(1);
    test.deleteNode(4);

    cout << endl << endl;

    test.printList();



}

List::List(){

    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

void List::addNode(int newData){

    node * n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = newData;

    if (head != NULL) { // List is intact

        curr = head; // if List is not empty, make curr equal to the head, and start at the beginning of the list.

        while(curr->next != NULL) { // Get to last item on the list
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n; // Use the last item, and point to the new node.
    }

    else { // empty list
        head = n; // new node is the head of the list.
    }
}

void List::deleteNode(int delData){

    node * n = new node;

    temp = head;
    curr = head;

    if (head != NULL) {
        while (curr!= NULL && curr->data != delData) {
            temp = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        if (temp->next == NULL) {
            cout << delData << " was not found in the list\n";
            delete n;
        }
        else {
            n = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            temp->next = curr;
            delete n;

            cout << delData << " was found and deleted\n";
        }
    }
}

void List::printList(){

    curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Allocating a new node in `deleteNode()` is also a design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

As @drescherjm said, that extra allocation could be skipped.
The final deletenode function is:

```
void List::deleteNode(int delData){

    node * n ;

    temp = head;
    curr = head;

    if (head != NULL) {
        while (curr!= NULL && curr->data != delData) {
            temp = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        if (temp->next == NULL) {
            cout << delData << " was not found in the list\n";
            // delete n;
        }
        else {
            n = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            temp->next = curr;
            delete n;

            cout << delData << " was found and deleted\n";
        }
    }
}
```